# Parsley.js - Messages (data-error-message and data-type-number-message)

Tags: validation, parsley.js

I want to use the *"data-error-message"* to display custom text for a filed if its not filled. Alternatively I want to show custom text *"data-type-number-message"* if the field does not contain a number.

They do not seem to work together? My code below...

```
<input name="port" type="text" id="port" size="25" data-required="true" data-error-message="Port is required." data-type="number" data-type-number-message="Numbers Only"/>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `data-required-message` instead of `data-error-message` for the `"Port is required"` message.
Also, you may want `digits` instead of `number` if this is for a port-number field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "data-error-message" or "data-parsley-error-message", depending on your install, for a generalized error response.